# Error Message in Java (Stream and Lambda Comprehension)

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I've been stuck for several hours trying to debug my code.

this is the error message that I get

`Error:(8, 8) java: trump.Wall is not abstract and does not override abstract method get() in java.util.function.Supplier`

these are the classes that corresponds to that error. So when I run the class `DonalTrump` it gave me the error message above. And apparently it is because of the `Wall` class. The following is my code

`DonaldTrump`

```
package trump;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

public class DonaldTrump{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 3) {
            System.out.println("Need three integer arguments: width height #bricks");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        int width = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int height = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int numberOfBricks = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        assert numberOfBricks <= width * height: "Too many bricks";
        System.out.printf("Will build a wall %d wide and %d tall%n",
                width, height);
        System.out.println(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(width,"==")));

        Wall trumpWall
        = Stream.generate(() -> new Ball(10.0))
                .filter(b -> b.colour == Ball.Colour.RED)
                .map(Brick::new)
                .limit(numberOfBricks)
                .collect(() -> new Wall(width, height), Wall::accept, Wall::combine); //UPDATE
        System.out.println(trumpWall);
    }
}
```

`//Wall SOURCE OF ERROR HERE`

```
package trump;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.*;


public class Wall implements Supplier<Wall> { //ERROR HERE//

    public Wall get() { //UPDATE
    return this;
    }

    private Brick[][] bricks;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int lastFilledX;
    private int lastFilledY;
    private boolean isComplete;

    final String sideBrick = "\u2b1b";
    final String innerBrick = " \u2b1b"; // black box (brick) in Unicode

    public Wall(int w, int h) {
        assert w > 0 && h > 0 : "the wall must have finite width and height";
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.bricks = new Brick[width][height];
        for (int j = 0; j < this.height; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < this.width; i++)
                this.bricks[i][j] = null;
        this.lastFilledX = 0;
        this.lastFilledY = 0;
        // this.isComplete = false;
    }

    public void lay(Brick brick) {
        if (this.isComplete()) return;
        this.bricks[lastFilledX][lastFilledY] = brick;
        // if (this.isComplete()) return false;
        if (this.lastFilledX == this.width - 1) {
            this.lastFilledX = 0;
            this.lastFilledY += 1;
        } else {
            this.lastFilledX += 1;
        }
    }

    public boolean isComplete() {
        return Stream.of(this.bricks).allMatch(
                level -> Stream.of(level).allMatch(b -> b != null));
        // return (this.lastFilledX == this.width - 1 &&
        //      this.lastFilledY == this.height - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (int j = this.height - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.width; i++)
                // try any from the range u25a2 -- u25a9
                buffer.append(bricks[i][j] == null ? "   " :
                        i == 0 ? sideBrick : innerBrick);
            // buffer.append(bricks[i][j] == 0 ? "0" : "1");
            buffer.append("\n");
        }
        // return "\033[31m" + buffer.toString() + "\033[0m";
        return buffer.toString(); // to hell with color code sequence
    }

    public static Wall linkTwoWalls(Wall w1, Wall w2) {
        assert w1.height == w2.height : "Walls have unequal height";
        if (!w1.isComplete() || !w2.isComplete())
            return null; //Optional.empty();
        int w = w1.width + w2.width;
        int h = w1.height;
        Brick[][] bricks = new Brick[w][h];
        System.arraycopy(w1, 0, bricks, 0, w1.width);
        System.arraycopy(w2, w1.width, bricks, 0, w2.width);
        Wall result = new Wall(w, h);
        result.bricks = bricks;
        return result;//Optional.of(result);
    }

    public static Optional<Wall> joinWalls(Wall... walls) {
        if (walls == null || walls.length == 0)
            return Optional.empty();
        // check all walls are of the same height
        int firstHeight = walls[0].height;
        Stream<Wall> wallStream = Stream.of(walls);
        assert wallStream.allMatch(w -> w.height == firstHeight);
        return wallStream.reduce((w1, w2) -> linkTwoWalls(w1, w2));
    }

    public void accept(Wall wall, Brick brick) { //UPDATE NOT STATIC
        wall.lay(brick);
    }

    public void combine(Wall w1, Wall w2) { //UPDATE NOT STATIC
        Wall.linkTwoWalls(w1, w2);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wall wall = new Wall(40, 10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 411; i++) {
            wall.lay(new Brick(new Ball(10.0)));
            if (wall.isComplete())
                break;
        }
        System.out.print(wall);
    }
}
```

Comment: You said `Wall` implements `Supplier`... then you didn't implement it.

Comment: #Rekt. But seriously, is this a real question?

Comment: Yes @Carcigenicate any ideas?

Comment: @Carcigenicate it seems so. The compile error message could not be more clear about it.

Comment: Why do you implement `Supplier` at all? The method reference is a supplier, the class does not need to implement it.

Comment: @Kutam Why do you have `implements Supplier<Wall>`? That basically means you want your wall to be function-like. Was that your intent? If it was, look at the answer below. Is maybe rethink that design though, as conceptually it didn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Carcigenicate because the argument in `DonaldTrump` class consist of three argument which is `(Wall(widht, height), Wall::accept, Wall::combine) that first argument is the Supplier which is 'Wall'

Comment: @Kutam That has nothing to do with the `Supplier` interface. See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) for more info

Comment: @Kutam I'm not sure what you mean, but I think you need to look over what it means to implement an interface. If you implement an interface, you need to actually implement the methods it requires. `get` in this case.

Comment: I think you are supposed to use `() -> new Wall(width, height)` as your supplier. The supplier *supplies* the item where the result will be accumulated.

Comment: where are you referring to? @RealSkeptic

Comment: In the first argument of `collect`.

Comment: @f1sh I asked if this is a real question because my troll-dar was going off. Still is :/

Comment: so I did this if thats what you mean `.collect(() -> new Wall(width, height), Wall::accept, Wall::combine);` but I still get the same error message @RealSkeptic

Comment: To debug your code `Brick` and `Ball` classes are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, I see 2 problems with your code:

1. You are not specifying a `Supplier<Wall>` in the call to `collect` in the `DonaldTrump` class, or you are doing it wrong. It's not correct to make your `Wall` class implement the `Supplier<Wall>` interface. Think of it in real life terms: it doesn't make sense that a wall is a supplier of itself. Instead, you should use a lambda expression that matches the `Supplier` interface, i.e. one that works *as if you were implementing* the `Supplier.get` method. This is `() -> new Wall(width, height)`.
2. In your `Wall` class, both the `accept` and `combine` methods shouldn't be static. Besides, `accept` should not revceive an instance of `Wall`, but only accept a `Brick`, which will be put into this `Wall`. Also, the `combine` method should accept only one `Wall` argument and combine this argument with this `Wall`. Maybe you could read the [lesson about method references in The Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), which clearly explains all the different method reference types and when to use each one of them.

Taking these items into account means that you should perform a few changes to your code.

In your `DonaldTrump` class, place the `() -> new Wall(width, height)` lambda expression as the `Supplier` of the `collect` method:

```
Wall trumpWall = Stream.generate(() -> new Ball(10.0))
    .filter(b -> b.colour == Ball.Colour.RED)
    .map(Brick::new)
    .limit(numberOfBricks)
    .collect(() -> new Wall(width, height), Wall::accept, Wall::combine);
```

And in your `Wall` class, change the `accept` and `combine` method as follows:

```
public void accept(Brick brick) { // Lay a brick into THIS wall
    this.lay(brick);
}

public void combine(Wall wanother) { // Combine another wall with THIS wall
    this.linkToThisWall(another);
}
```

Where `linkToThisWall` would be a modified version of your (now useless) `linkTwoWalls` method:

```
public void linkToThisWall(Wall another) {
    assert this.height == another.height : "Walls have unequal height";
    if (!this.isComplete() || !another.isComplete()) {
        return; // or maybe throw an exception?
    }        
    int w = this.width + another.width;
    int h = this.height;
    Brick[][] newBricks = new Brick[w][h];
    System.arraycopy(this.bricks, 0, newBricks, 0, this.width);
    System.arraycopy(another.bricks, this.width, bricks, 0, another.width);
    this.bricks = newBricks;
}
```

Consider also removing the `get` method, as implementing `Supplier<Wall>` is no longer needed.

Actually, with this code fix and refactoring, you no longer need the `accept` and `combine` methods. In your `DonaldTrump` class, you could just use references to the refactored `lay` and `linkToThisWall` methods instead:

```
Wall trumpWall = Stream.generate(() -> new Ball(10.0))
    .filter(b -> b.colour == Ball.Colour.RED)
    .map(Brick::new)
    .limit(numberOfBricks)
    .collect(() -> new Wall(width, height), Wall::lay, Wall::linkToThisWall);
```

**EDIT:** The main reason for these changes is that you were not using the `Stream.collect` method correctly.

`Stream.collect` expects 3 arguments:

1. A supplier that will be used to create a cumulative, *mutable* structure where to accumulate the elements of the stream. In your code, this structure is a `Wall` and the elements of the stream are instances of `Brick`, so the supplier is `() -> new Wall(width, height)`. This supplier might be seen as an empty wall, i.e. like a place in the ground where to start laying bricks.
2. An accumulator, which is a `BiConsumer` that accepts two arguments: the structure returned by the previous item's supplier and an element of the stream. The contract for this accumulator biconsumer is that it has to accumulate one element of the stream into the cumulative, mutable structure. In your case, the cumulative, mutable structure is the `Wall` created by the supplier above and the elements of the stream are instances of `Brick`, so the accumulator is `Wall::lay`, or using a lambda `(wall, brick) -> wall.lay(brick)`. This accumulator might be seen as a worker laying bricks into a wall, one by one.
3. A combiner, which is a `BiConsumer` that accepts two arguments, both being instances of a partially filled, mutable structure (these structures have the same type as the structure supplied by the `Supplier` of item 1). This combiner is to be used when the creation of the final structure can be parallelized, and its contract is to combine (or merge, or mix, or link or join) the second argument structure into the first argument structure. In your case, the partially filled, mutable structures are two `Wall` instances partially filled with bricks, so the combiner is `Wall::linkToThisWall`, or using a lambda `(leftWall, rightWall) -> leftWall.linkToThisWall(rightWall)`. All this combining stuff might be seen as two separate workers working in parallel, each one working by laying bricks into his own wall: one worker would start on the left and the other one would start in the right; when they meet in the middle, both half walls are combined into a new full wall.

As to why your solution was incorrect... Your combiner was wrong. You are not supposed to create a new, empty structure and merge the two structures provided as arguments into this new structure. Instead, you should merge the second argument structure into the first argument structure. This is why your static `linkTwoWalls` method didn't work: you were merging two walls into a new one and you were returning this new wall from that static method. However, that returned wall was being discarded, because the combiner must be a `BiConsumer` that merges second into first argument. (Yours was actually a `BinaryOperator`, i.e. you were creating a new wall from two walls and returning it, as when you sum two numbers and get another number as a result). However, you were not using a parallel stream, so your combiner was never used.

Comment: I have updated the code with your suggestions. Can you check it again? Also when I try to run it, this is what I get `Error:(44, 17) java: no suitable method found for collect(()->new Wa[...]ight),Wall::accept,Wall::combine)
    method java.util.stream.Stream....`

Comment: The code actually works when I introduce the get() method. But that works when both accept() and combine method() is as static. But when I remove the static. It produces an error (the comment above)

Comment: Greatly appreciated, this is actually the approach that my tutor wants. can you explain to me why this is better as oppose to the working solution that I got earlier with the get() method and both accept and combine as static.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to override the [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html#get--) method of the Supplier interface.

```
public Wall get(){
      return this;
}
```

Comment: but the `Supplier` interface is built-in. Its part of Java 8. How do I change it?

Comment: sorry, I didn't get you..?

Comment: Yes, it's built in. But it's an interface. So when you declare that a class implements that interface (which is what ``Wall`` does), you need to declare the ``get()`` method (because it must be present in all instances of ``Supplier``). You didn't specify a ``get()`` method in Wall.

Comment: @Kutam You said your class implements Supplier. You need at least the code above to implement Supplier. This doesn't have anything to do with changing the Supplier interface, only implementing the required method of the Supplier interface.

Comment: I added the get() method in wall, now it doesnt stop and I need to force quit intellij. Ive updated the `Wall` class. Can you check it please @f1sh @Carcigenicate

Comment: @Kutam please do _not_ change the context of the question(_don't_ edit the question when your problem is already solved), the problem you've got now is a different matter. This is more to do with your implementation than what I've suggested.

Comment: Sorry, but I wasnt changing the context. I added your suggestion in the class `Wall` but now it wont stop running. You can check the updated question, I put your suggestion in the wall class.

Comment: @Kutam if the program is not stopping you'll need to reconsider your implementation, maybe even use the debugger to track down the cause of it.

Comment: Im only asking because it doesnt stop since I input your suggestion in the `Wall` class. Like is this the case, or maybe I may have input your suggestion in the wrong place or something. Im just trying to get help @Aominè thats why I told you to look in the updated `Wall` class